# Get file path + file name in a keybindings file in Sublime Text 2

Tags: key-bindings, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm trying to get the path of the current file + the file's name (without extension) in a Key Binding file in Sublime Text 2. `$file_path` or `${file_path}` are both not working.

The reason is that I want to execute an *.exe file, which was built before (but don't want to both build and execute in one step). Any ideas?

Greetz

Comment: Why did you specify "without extension"?  The task sounds like it would be fairly simple with a plugin.  I don't think there is a way to do what you want purely in the sublime keybinding file.

Comment: Because I want to perform the shortcut in the *.c or *.cpp file, from which i build the *.exe before.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the [sublime-snippet](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html), this is my code:

```
#filename: filename.sublime-snippet
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[$TM_FILENAME]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>fn</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>the current file name</description>
</snippet>
```

when you type 'fn' in python source files, you will get your filename.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime offers a command called `copy_path` which will copy the current file's absolute path to the clipboard. Unfortunately, this includes the file extension. But if you're familiar with how to roll your own quick plugin, you can issue `copy_path` therein, and perform some basic string manipulation to strip the file extension. If not though, you can bind `copy_path` to a key combination and work from there.