# In Sublime Text 2 how can I pass the current file path to a command called by a key binding

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I'm working with sublime text 2 build 2221, on Windows 8; python 2.7.

I want to pass the name of the file I'm currently working on in st2 to a command by calling a key binding like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+2"],"command": "run_me", "args":{"cmd":"$1"} }
```

where `"$1"` gets replaced with the name of the file in the current view, i.e. the file I'm looking at when hitting the keys. How would I go about this?

My script for `run_me` looks like this:

```
class runMeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        cmd_string = kwargs["cmd"]
        os.system("start "+cmd_string)
```

I found the following references [here](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/writing-simple-sublime-text-plugin) and [here](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/snippets.html?highlight=TM_FILENAME#environment-variables) which seem to talk about this but I couldn't get it to work.

Relevant quotes from the links:

```
Link 1:
...
"args": {
      "contents": "console.log('=== HEARTBEAT $TM_FILENAME [$TM_LINE_NUMBER] ===');${0}"
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Link 2:
$TM_FILENAME    Filename of the file being edited including extension.
```

Comment: Also had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847204/get-filename-filepath-in-a-keybindings-file-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1) which seems quite similar

Comment: Can you give some more information on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to write a snippet or a plugin to perform some other action with the file name?

Comment: @skuroda I added the `run_me` command. I would like to redirect the file name to the shell via an `os.system` or `subprocess` call. Thanks

Comment: I also found a [discussion here](http://superuser.com/questions/584294/sublime-text-2-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-tool). There, it seems, `"$file_basename"` is used, which returns the string `$filename` rather than the actual file name when I send it to my string. Is it possible that I have to deal with this in my script? I.e. searching for strings like `$file_name` and replacing them with the actual file name using `view.file_name()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the way to do it (HT @skuroda):

```
class runMeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            if "$file_name" in kwargs["cmd"]:
                cur_view = self.window.active_view()
                cmd_string=kwargs["cmd"].replace("$file_name",cur_view.file_name())
                os.system("start "+cmd_string)
            else:
                os.system("start "+cmd_string)
        except TypeError:
            sublime.message_dialog("Something went wrong with the command given... \n\n\n"+traceback.format_exc())
```

And the key binding looks like this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+3"],"command": "run_me", "args":{"cmd":"echo $file_name"} }
```

If the runMe class will always only get one argument only there is no need to use `**kwargs`:

```
def run(self, cmd):
    try:
        if "$file_name" in cmd:
            cur_view = self.window.active_view()
            cmd_string=cmd.replace("$file_name",cur_view.file_name())
            os.system("start "+cmd_string)
        else:
            cmd_string=cmd
            os.system("start "+cmd_string)
    except TypeError:
        sublime.message_dialog("Something went wrong with the command given... \n\n\n"+traceback.format_exc())
```

The key binding would be the same as above.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. You can grab the absolute path using `view#file_name`, then substitute it as  you would like. Some small things (that may not matter), you can use `cmd` as your arg so you don't have to look through the kargs map. Also note that `view#file_name` may return None if it doesn't exist on disk, so you may want to add a check for that also. Finally, you could also use a TextCommand to get access to the view (it would be `self.view.file_name). If you want to use the window command still, you should use `self.window` rather than `sublime.Window`.